# Bash script - if statement inconsistency

Tags: bash, shell

I'm learning how to write scripts, and am having an issue with an if statement. The script reads in user input for their scores, and calculates their average grade. However, if the user enters a score lower than 0 or greater than 100, the script should ask them to re-enter a valid value. Here is the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCORE=0
AVERAGE=0
SUM=0
NUM=0

while true
do
    # Read score from user
    echo -n "Enter your score [0-100] ('q' for quit): "; read SCORE

    # Validate user input
    if (($SCORE < 0)) || (($SCORE > 100))
    then
        echo "Invalid input, try again: "
    #elif (( $SCORE == "q" )) 
    elif [ "$SCORE" == "q" ]
    then
        echo "Average rating: $AVERAGE%."
        break
    else
        # Perform calculation
        SUM=$[$SUM + $SCORE]
        NUM=$[$NUM +1]
        AVERAGE=$[$SUM / $NUM]
        echo "Average rating: $AVERAGE%"
    fi
done
```

Notice I have the `elif` commented out. When I write that elif with `[]` notation, it works as expected. However, if I switch to the elif which uses `(())`, and enter "00" as my score, the program executes the "then" block on and exits. Why is it doing that? 00 is not 'q'.

Comment: I'm guessing that the $SCORE evaluation needs to be evaluated itself before evaluated in the conditional statement. Since $SCORE is 00 after evaluated, which the square brackets cause, the conditional statement fails. However, when assigning a value, the condition is always "true" (i.e. "if x=foo return true" would return true).

Comment: `$[ ... ]` is legacy syntax. Bash supports it for compatibility with ancient pre-POSIX shells (which is to say, shells from before 1991), but unlike `$(( ))`, it isn't guaranteed to available on baseline-POSIX shells -- it doesn't work, for instance, with `ash` or `dash`.

Comment: And `==` isn't guaranteed to work inside `[ ]` either -- the POSIX-compliant string comparison operator is just `=`. If you want bashisms, use `[[ ]]` to make it explicit that you're relying on extended syntax rather than intending to use portable constructs.

Comment: Also, it's ideal to avoid all-caps names for your own variables -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph: *The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities* -- keeping in mind that setting a shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable.

Comment: You are not having problems with the `if` statement but with the *command* which follows it.  The brackets are not exclusively part of the `if` syntax.  `(( ... ))` and `[[ ... ]]` are *compound commands* whereas `[` is a shell builtin.  The syntax for `if` is actually `if ` *list* `then` *list* `fi`.

Comment: *nod*. That mistake is why a lot of folks think they need something like `if [ "$(grep -e content filename)" ]; then ...` rather than the correct, much simpler, and faster-to-execute `if grep -q -e content filename; then ...`.

Comment: (BTW, `echo -n` is also best avoided; `printf '%s' "content to be printed with no newline"` is more portable: [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) leaves behavior entirely undefined whenever `-n` is in use -- and, incidentally, outright disallows `-e` doing anything but printing itself as a string in output. And while bash uses a noncompliant extended `echo` by default, that can be toggled by runtime or compile-time configuration, so it's unsafe to rely on).

Answer (score 5):

The line `(( $SCORE == "q" ))` does not work for the exact reason you are suggesting. The `((..))` is only meant for arithmetic operations and string operations cannot be done within it. You need to use the `test` operator `[` or `[[` for it.

Quoting from the GNU `bash` documentation

> #### 6.5 Shell Arithmetic
>
> The shell allows arithmetic expressions to be evaluated, as one of the shell expansions or by using the `((` compound command, the `let` builtin, or the `-i` option to the `declare` builtin.
>
> Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers with no check for overflow, though division by 0 is trapped and flagged as an error. The operators and their precedence, associativity, and values are the same as in the `C` language.

Some of the standard expression involving strings when used with the classic `test` operator (`[`)

```
Operator                         Syntax-Description
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-z <STRING>                True, if <STRING> is empty.
-n <STRING>                True, if <STRING> is not empty (this is the default operation).
<STRING1> = <STRING2>      True, if the strings are equal.
<STRING1> != <STRING2>     True, if the strings are not equal.
```

The one you have used `[ "$SCORE" == "q" ]` is synonymous to using `[ "$SCORE" = "q" ]` in a way only literal string match is performed but *not* `POSIX` compatible as the latter.

The `==` comparison operator behaves differently within a double-brackets than within single brackets (both literal & glob matching)

```
[[ $a == z* ]]   # True if $a starts with an "z" (pattern matching).
[[ $a == "z*" ]] # True if $a is equal to z* (literal matching).
```

---

Also you could re-write your statements entirely in arithmetic context using the `((..))` operator over the legacy `$[ ... ]` operator.

```
sum=$((sum + score))
((num++))
(( num != 0 )) && average=$(( sum / num ))

printf "%0.2f\n" $num
```

Note that I have lowercased the variable names to distinguish them from the environment variables (shell system variables) but just as user define variables. And used `printf` over `echo` to introduce `POSIX` guaranteed floating point formatting options which `echo` does not allow.